# Azure API Management with on-premise API

Tags: azure, security, azure-api-management

Is there any reference to use Azure API management with on premise APIs?  How the security works here?  any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could put your on-premise APIs into VNET with APIM in the cloud: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet.
2. You could use on-premise APIM (in preview): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-arc-enabled-api-management-is-now-available-in-preview/.

Comment: Once on premise API moved to VNET, those APIs are became  not on premise now .. I was looking azure api management routing the calls to an on premise API.

Comment: Look at option 2 above, then. It allows you to host APIM runtime component completely inside your own infrastructure.

Comment: I noticed another approach as well using Azure AD Proxy Application to register on premise API as proxy AD application in Azure. Then enable Application Proxy in Azure Active Directory. Any inputs to this approach mentioned here, https://stephaneeyskens.wordpress.com/2017/05/22/creative-way-of-exposing-on-premises-apis-through-azure-api-management/

Comment: Wouldn't that result in a publicly accessible, albeit authenticated, endpoint that allows you to call into your on-premise APIs?