# Azure API Management Setup for Non Azure API

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a REST point say **xyz.com/getValues** as a back end service. This is not a resouce of azure. I can call this end point from postman with proper BODY as a **POST** request. It works generally fine. Now I have got an **OPEN API specification** for this and I imported onto Azure API management. I set the backend service to xyz.com. But while testing it, I received **500 Internal server error**. And in traces I found below error.

**forward-request (139.450 ms)
{
"messages": [
"Error occured while calling backend service.",
"The remote name could not be resolved: 'xyz.com'"
]
}**

There are some points I would like to mention.

1. I am using consumption tier of Azure API management.
2. xyz.com is not a public service. It is just an application deployed in company network.
   I need suggestion on how to reach this as a solution. I am doing a POC and new to Azure API Management. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59796482/3652378

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Melissa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3652378/melissa). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.
Need to put non-azure API's into VNET and then you can use that in APIM  on azure
[image]

We can use Non Azure APIM's

Azure Arc enabled API Management allows customers to leverage a self-hosted API gateway, that expands [API Management](https://aka.ms/apimrocks) support for hybrid and multi-cloud environments and enables Azure customers to efficiently and securely manage APIs hosted on-premises and across clouds from a single API Management service in Azure.

[Click Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#-enable-vnet-connection) for VNET configuration with APIM

Check [Non-Azure APIM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-arc-enabled-api-management-is-now-available-in-preview/) to use APIs

Open the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59796482/15969833) for further inputs.